# encrypt data in PostgreSQL using ORM

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to encrypt the data in the PostgreSQL. I am using the below two methods to insert the data, one using ORM, other without ORM

```
db = sql.create_engine(connection_string)
metadata = sql.schema.MetaData(bind=db, reflect=True)
inputStringtable = sql.Table('person_info', metadata, autoload=True)

######Using ORM########
class RowInputString(object):
    pass
orm.Mapper(RowInputString, inputStringtable)
Sess = orm.sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Sess()

inputTable = RowInputString()
inputTable.person_id = personId
inputTable.person_name = personName
session.add(inputTable)
session.commit()
################################

######not using ORM
def inserting_data(personId, personName):
    insertData = inputStringtable.insert().values(person_id=personId, person_name=personName)
    conn = db.connect()
    conn.execute(ins)
inserting_data(personId, personName)
```

I came across the below snippet to the encrypt and send it to database:

```
INSERT INTO users(login, passwd)
VALUES('my_login', crypt('my_password', gen_salt('md5')));
```

I find it little difficult how I can use this snippet in my code?

Comment: it looks as if [`crypt`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/pgcrypto.html) hashes a password with a salt. this would be one-way: it would  be computationally infeasable to get the plaintext (`my_password`) back. that is not your use-case as far as i understand...

Comment: On the other hand passwords should not be stored encrypted, but hashed.

Answer (score 1):

For general encryption, you can use the [`EncryptedType`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type) SQLAlchemy type.

For password hashing you can define a custom type in SQLAlchemy:

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/DatabaseCrypt

This uses `bind_expression` of the [TypeDecorator API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator) to map the passed-in column value to an expression involving built-in database functions (`gen_salt` and `crypt`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I am able to encrypt using EncryptedType and store in the database. May I know how I can decrypt it?

Comment: May I know how can I decrypt it?